# Necessary and sufficient for convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Xn converges in probability to X does not necessarily imply convergence in mean,but is it true that Xn converges in probability to X iff $E(  |Xn-X|/(1+(|Xn-X|)))$ goes to 0?

This could be a nice criteria to check the convergence in probability.So I am interested in this.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes.  The metric $E\min(1,|X-Y|))$ metrizes convergence in probability, and thus so does $E(|X-Y|/(1+|X-Y|))$. See p.306 of the English language version of Bogachev's _Measure Theory_.

Comment: thanks for the information,,i will look it up.

Comment: can you suggest a proof using basic things like chebyshev's inequality and dominated convergence theorem etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $\psi(t)=t/(1+t)$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, so by Chebyshev's inequality, $$P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\le \frac {E\psi(|X_n-X|)}{\psi(\epsilon)}.$$

Suppose $E\psi(|X_n-X|)\to0$.For fixed $\epsilon>0$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\le \frac {\lim_{n\to\infty}E\psi(|X_n-X|)}{\psi(\epsilon)} = 0.$$
So  $E\psi(|X_n-X|)\to0$ implies  $ P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\to0$, that is, implies $X_n\to X$ in probability.

This proves the "if" part of "converges in probability if and only if $E[\psi(|X_n-X|)\to0$".  Here is an argument for the converse.
Observe that $\psi(t)\le\min(1,|t|)$.  Suppose $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$.  Then for each positive $\epsilon$, we have $P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<\epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.  For such values of $n$, we have $\psi(|X_n-X|)\le\epsilon$ for all values whenever $[|X_n-X|\le\epsilon]$ holds, and in the contrary case, which holds with probability at most $\epsilon$, we have $\psi(|X_n-X|)\le1$.  Putting these two together we get $$E[\psi(|X_n-X|)]\le \epsilon P[|X_n-X|\le\epsilon]+P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]]\le2\epsilon.$$ This then  implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[\psi(|X_n-X|)] = 0$.

Comment: absolutely,i got it. so the catch is here that that function is increasing on that interval.sometimes i miss those nice but elementary observations.Anyways,thanks for your time.

Comment: ok,so can u say something about the converse of what you have proved?

Comment: Why don't you have a try, yourself, using the monotonicity of what I call $\psi$? It's just another $\epsilon-\delta$ exercise.