# show that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ iff $E\left(\frac{|X_n−X|}{1+|X_n−X|}\right)$ goes to 0?

Tags: probability

How to show that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ iff $E\left(\frac{|X_n−X|}{1+|X_n−X|}\right)$  goes to 0?

Here I did not understand the proof
[Necessary and sufficient for convergence in probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208699/necessary-and-sufficient-for-convergence-in-probability)

I know the definition of convergence in probability which is as follows,

The sequence of rv  ${X_n}$ converge to a r.v. $X$, all have same sample space, if $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0$, for any given $\epsilon>0$.

How to prove this?

Comment: What about the answer did you not understand?

Comment: Please show some attempt and ideally the arguments you would like to use.

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208699/necessary-and-sufficient-for-convergence-in-probability, The function $ψ(t)=t/(1+t)$
 is increasing on $[0,∞)$
, so by Chebyshev's inequality,
$P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\le \frac {E\psi(|X_n-X|)}{\psi(\epsilon)}.
$
I want to know the required theorem for increasing function...

Comment: Should I have to use the generalized Tchebycheff's inequality? $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{E(X_n-X)^2}{\epsilon^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}$ is strictly increasing for $x\geq 0$.

$(\Leftarrow)$
$$P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)=\frac{\varepsilon + 1}{\varepsilon}\int_{\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}}\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} dP\leq \frac{\varepsilon + 1}{\varepsilon}\int\frac{|X_n-X|}{1+|X_n-X|} dP\to 0$$
$(\Rightarrow)$
$$\begin{aligned}\int\frac{|X_n-X|}{1+|X_n-X|} dP&=\int_{\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}}\underbrace{\frac{|X_n-X|}{1+|X_n-X|}}_{<1} dP+\int_{\{|X_n-X|\leq \varepsilon\}}\frac{|X_n-X|}{1+|X_n-X|} dP\leq \\
&\leq P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)+\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}P(|X_n-X|\leq \varepsilon)\stackrel{n\to \infty}\to\\
&\stackrel{n\to \infty}\to 0+\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\stackrel{\varepsilon \to 0}{\to}0
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Please explore $P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)=\frac{\varepsilon + 1}{\varepsilon}\int_{\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}}\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} dP\leq \frac{\varepsilon + 1}{\varepsilon}\int\frac{|X_n-X|}{1+|X_n-X|} dP$

I know that $P(g(X))\geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{E(g(x))}{\epsilon}$, are you using this?

Comment: Note: @user1942348
$$\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}}\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\leq \mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\}}\frac{|X_n-X|}{1+|X_n-X|}\leq \frac{|X_n-X|}{1+|X_n-X|}$$